# error with login.php not loading up on browser

Tags: php, html

login page not picking up the code when loading the page on the browser.

```
<!--
Here, we write code for login.
-->
<?php

require_once('connection.php');
$email = $password = $pwd = '';

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pwd = $_POST['password'];
$password = MD5($pwd);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE Email='$email' AND Password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $id = $row["ID"];
        $email = $row["Email"];
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    }
    header("Location: welcome.php");
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid email or password";
}
?>
```

the error that i got is

> Notice: Undefined index: email in F:\HND Second Year\Semester 1\Aram\website_DB_New\Unit_35_Website_Database\USBWebserver v8.6\root\login_code.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined index: password in F:\HND Second Year\Semester 1\Aram\website_DB_New\Unit_35_Website_Database\USBWebserver v8.6\root\login_code.php on line 10
>        Invalid email or password

Comment: Where is your html form?

Comment: **Warning!** - Don't use md5() for hashing passwords. md5 is old, fast and broken. Use PHP's [password_hash()](https://php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](https://php.net/manual/de/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Comment: Please consult a recent tutorial. Don't use md5 and don't put user input into SQL. Parameterize. Your `<!--
Here, we write code for login.
-->` also is likely to make your `header` not work.

Comment: try printr($_POST) and show us what you get

Comment: sorry i am new to this coding, i do not understand what needs to be done

Comment: also, show us what's in connection.php

Comment: @DCR which line should i put this in?

Comment: just before $email = $_POST...

Comment: <!--
in this file we write code for connection with database.
-->
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","usbw","pearl_bazaar");

if(!$conn)
{
 echo "Database connection failed";
}
?>

Comment: It would appear that the login script is run before the form is submitted and that's what's causing your problem.

Comment: @DCR
Fatal error: Call to undefined function printr() in F:\HND Second Year\Semester 1\Aram\website_DB_New\Unit_35_Website_Database\USBWebserver v8.6\root\login_code.php on line 10

Comment: how can i fix this problem then please

Comment: sorry about that, it's print_r($_POST)

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score -1):

it is not error,it is warning.
as you see it is warning.
before set the global $_post ,you should check it with isset function.

it means like if isset($_post['email ']) then do the work!

Comment: It is called `$_POST` not `$_post`

Comment: i have another error...

Comment: Array ( [Email] => nadia.rashid0786@gmail.com [Password] => pakistan [login] => ) 
Notice: Undefined index: password in F:\HND Second Year\Semester 1\Aram\website_DB_New\Unit_35_Website_Database\USBWebserver v8.6\root\login_code.php on line 11
 Invalid email or password

Comment: $id = $row["Register_ID"];      this line of code is the name given to the ID in the register table

Comment: i have just altered it in the code

Comment: while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  $id = $row["Register_ID"];
  $email = $row["Email"];
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['Register_ID'] = $id;
  $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
 }

Comment: this is the welcome code...............             <?php
include_once('link.php');
include_once('header1.php');
require_once('connection.php');

$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$usrname = $email = '';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE ID='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  $usrname = $row["Username"];
  $email = $row["Email"];
 }
}

?>

Comment: could you please check if the code is ok in the welcome code